# Is there a name for this Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \circ_G)$ be a group. Then, let

$$F(G) = \left(G^{(G^2)}, (f, g) \mapsto \big((x, y) \mapsto f(x, y) \circ_G g(x, y)\big)\right)$$

be the group of all functions from $G^2 \to G$, with the operation of applying $\circ_G$ pointwise. The identity is the function $(x, y) \mapsto e_G$, where $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$. $F(G)$ being a group follows from the already known group operation $\circ_G$.

Is there a name for this group?

Comment: Do you want the functions to be continuous? Edit: Oh wait, these aren't the circle and the sphere, are they?

Comment: No. Since I begin with an arbitrary group $S$, I don't even think we can ask for continuity unless we ask for specific restrictions on which groups we begin with. (I am unsure what you mean by "circle and the sphere")

Comment: Usually $S^1$ is the unit circle, an important topological group, and $S^2$ is the unit sphere. Spaces of maps to or from $S^1$ are common enough that using the letter S here is short-circuiting my poor brain!

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll change $S$ to $G$ then.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know the name of your group, it is simply a particular form of the direct product $\prod\limits_{\alpha \in A}\,G$ for an arbitrary set $A$.  Note that $\prod\limits_{\alpha\in A}\,G$ can be viewed as the set of all functions $A\to G$ with the pointwise multiplication as the group operation.  In your case, $A=G^2$.

Comment: So according to your answer, $F(G) = G^{|G^2|}$?

Comment: I don't usually write that notation, because it seems ambiguous (there is also a notion of weak direct products of groups).  But sure, with the usual definition, your group is basically $G^{G^2}\cong G^{\left|G^2\right|}$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your claim. You say $\prod_{\alpha \in A} G$ can be viewed as the set of all functions $A \to G$. However, if $|G| = 3$ and $|A| = 2$, we have $6$ such functions, but $\left|\prod_{\alpha \in A} G\right| = |G^2| = 9$

Comment: There are $9$ functions, not $6$.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, you are correct. I'm having a bit of a hard time seeing the isomorphism between this (possibly infinite) direct product, and $F(G)$, but I will take a closer look. Thank you